How to do a high input count similar to addressable LEDs
I'm trying to find an IC or something similar with a high input count that can compare sensors in a simple matrix and trigger an output.
Matrix would be:
0+0=0
1+0=0
0+1=0
1+1=1 (output on)

I need to compare 500 sensors to 500 sensors that are facing each other. Very low current outputs.
My thought is if addressable LEDs can be done in an output fashion with an arduino setup there should be a way to do one that handles inputs and converts them into numbers. Essentially the opposite of the way the LED addressing works. I'm a bit of an electrical person but this is beyond my current knowledge and searching has been tricky as I lack the vernacular to describe what I'm looking for. This would be easy with a PLC but 1000 inputs would be very cumbersome to work with. If there is a way to have it input the signals with something like CAN or another communication that can be done with something similar to way the LED ribbon works it would be ideal.

Is it necessary to identify the/one pair of sensors "with 1+1" (if that is what it is), or is at least one pair active all it takes? (compare 500 sensors to 500 sensors that are facing each other in pairs, probably, considering 0+0=0 1+0=0 0+1=0 1+1=1. Routing all those signals using cables/traces may be the bigger challenge.)

Add more information: What are the sensor outputs? Is it 500 mutually exclusive pairs you're dealing with? How frequently do you have to check the condition/sensor(s) state? Why do you need all these sensors?

Due to the number of inputs, lots of cabling will be involved, so you have to think about using a number of N modules with M inputs each (N*M=1000 inputs), so you can put the modules in convenient places to minimize cabling, while having them communicate using a more economical protocol (CAN, wifi, ethernet or otherwise). If the 1000 inputs are spread all over a building this can save lots of wiring work! So please add details about this to your question. Also what kind of reaction time you need, input voltage, and available power sources.

For example an ESP32 has 20 inputs and can send them to a central brainbox via wifi, which could be great in some situations, but it wouldn't work if the system is spread over a square kilometer or you can't tolerate the non-100% reliability of wifi, or it would be overkill if the system fits in a small room and you can use cables and shift registers. Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696101

@greybeard Think of it as a comparator that checks top to bottom. The addressed IO similar to the LED's system would be the solution as the bulk is the problem. Breaking them up into chunks that could be linked together via normal IP addressing via an RJ45 or something would be a possible solution if its not "in line" like the LED's system.

@MOSFET  The length is over 14' so the "resloution" is higher. I added some context above that the sensor is a comparator of sorts. This a ground up idea so the power and shapes/forms are flexible but will probably be just 5 or 24VDC. AS far as response goes fast is better and shouldn't be an issue if it can be done via the sensors calling their addresses out per sweep for the PLC/Arduino. I say addresses because the bulk of running 1000 IO's is absolutely an issue I'd like to avoid but I lack the technical vernacular to search for a chip similar to the LED strip's operation principles.

@bobflux I was only allowed one tag per comment. Much thanks for the replies! I did not expect such thorough responses, so quickly. I will make it a point to check back much more frequently.

What are you trying to build? If it's 14 inches long it sounds like a digital caliper or something... Sensor datasheet would help.

@bobflux It's 14 feet in length. Haven't chosen the sensor yet because of the input count issue. My thinking is making any sensor input work is easier than coordinating the sensors. I'll be leaning toward small magnetic/metal sensing proxes with a small physical size.

You should really give more details

In the very particular case where the 'inputs' are mechanical switches or similar (such as reed capsules) and where '1' represents an isolated closed contact and '0' represents an open contact you can connect them in series pairs with a diode, and connect those in an X by Y matrix like LEDs.
For example, in the below schematic you would drive one of COL0/COL1 etc. high at a time and read all of A, B etc. voltages. By scanning the complete matrix you can read each pair and determine any pairs where both switches are simultaneously closed.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If your 'inputs' are something else it will be more complex and you might want to think about making a PCB to hand some reasonable number of inputs (like 10 or 20 or 50) that can be made to handle the logic and daisy chained or otherwise serially accessed.

You kinda have the idea. The illustration shows the issue of the bulk being an issue here. I'm pretty resigned to the idea that I'd need to make a PCB of some sort to do this but I don't speak PCB design well enough to search a chip that can handle addressing.
